# How to create a number of Fields dynamically in Blackberry Java SDK 5.0?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde, blackberry-basiceditfield

I'm trying to create a couple of `BasicEditField` objects after i get the **number** of fields that i want from an `ObjectChoiceField`.

Problem: the `BasicEditField` fields that i add to my screen don't refresh unless i do it in the listener from my `ObjectChoiceField`.

what i want to do :

1. select the number of `BasicEditFields` that i want.
2. refresh the screen so the fields added appear.

PD: if you need more info, just tell me, and sorry about my english.  I'm new at developing for the BlackBerry plataform

```java
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
    private int fields_lenght;

    public MyScreen()
    {        
        // Set the displayed title of the screen       
        setTitle("Example");
        fields_lenght =0;

        final String shortcodes[] = {"1","2","3"};
        final ObjectChoiceField dropdownlist=new ObjectChoiceField("Select a number of fields",shortcodes);
        this.add(dropdownlist);

        dropdownlist.setChangeListener( new FieldChangeListener() {

            public void fieldChanged( Field arg0, int arg1 ) {
                    if(arg1 != PROGRAMMATIC){
                        fields_lenght= Integer.parseInt(shortcodes[dropdownlist.getSelectedIndex()]);
                    }
            }
        } );

        // how to refresh the screen with the new fields ???

            BasicEditField fields[]=new BasicEditField [fields_lenght] ;

            for(int i = 0; i<fields.length;i++){
                fields[i]=new BasicEditField("Campo "+i,"");
                this.add(fields[i]);
            }

     }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are adding your new BasicEditFields? (just click the **edit** link below the question and add the code into your question)  Also, is there a reason why you **don't** want to do it in the ObjectChoiceField listener?

Comment: @Nate Hello Nate well now you can see an example of what i want to do.

Comment: @Nate  I didnt want to use it in the ObjectChoiceField listener because it add more fields than i need since the listener take the trackwheel click and movement as the same action, i tryed to override trackwheel click and movement but it didnt work. Also i would like to delete the fields , for example if the choice change to 2 from 3 wich means i would have to delete one field. I hope i explained myself. i read about Invalidate() method from the screen but i dont really understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really *should* add or delete the fields from within your `ObjectChoiceField` listener.  That's when you know what the proper number of fields is.  (Certainly, if you just want to keep your code neat and clean, you could define a separate *method*, that is called from the choice field listener ... that's not much different).

Try something like this:

```java
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

   /** A cached vector of the BasicEditFields, to make deleting easier */
   private Vector fields;

   public MyScreen() {
      super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

      setTitle("Example");

      final String shortcodes[] = {"1","2","3"};
      final ObjectChoiceField dropdownlist = new ObjectChoiceField("Select a number of fields", shortcodes);
      add(dropdownlist);

      fields = new Vector();
      final Screen screen = this;

      dropdownlist.setChangeListener( new FieldChangeListener() {

         public void fieldChanged( Field field, int context ) {
            if (context != PROGRAMMATIC) {
               // how many fields has the user chosen?
               int fieldsLength = Integer.parseInt(shortcodes[dropdownlist.getSelectedIndex()]);

               while (fieldsLength > fields.size()) {
                  // we need to ADD more fields
                  Field f = new BasicEditField("Campo " + fields.size(), "");
                  fields.addElement(f);
                  screen.add(f);
               }

               while (fieldsLength < fields.size()) {
                  // we need to DELETE some fields
                  Field f = (Field)fields.elementAt(fields.size() - 1);
                  fields.removeElement(f);
                  screen.delete(f);
               }                                         
            }
         }
      });
   }
```

I defined a new member named `fields`, which just makes it easier to keep track of the basic edit fields (in case this screen has many other fields, too).

When the choice field listener is called, I determine how many fields the user wants; if they need more, I add them to the screen, and to the `fields` Vector.  If they want fewer, I delete some fields from the end of the Vector, and remove them from the Screen.

*Note: there should be no need to call `invalidate()` here.  Calling `Screen#add()` or `Screen#delete()` should add/delete the fields and cause repainting.*

Comment: wow thanks Nate i don't know what i was doing that inside of listener he understand the trackwheel movement as a trackwheel click so even when he just navigated by the list it chose something. Anyways the code that you gave me worked fine , thanks bro have a nice day!